# listbox doesn't show displaymember

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a `ListBox`, and it has a `Binding` to `dtAtt`, but when I run the app, the ListBox show the items with empty content.

Code:

Xaml:

```
<Expander Name="expandAtt" Header="Attachment">
    <ListBox x:Name="lstAtt" MouseDoubleClick="lstAtt_MouseDoubleClick" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
    </ListBox>
</Expander>
```

C#:

```
    public DataTable  dtAtt;

    string sql = "SELECT Name FROM Item2Inv_Link";
    dtAtt = DataBase.GetTable(sql);
    lstAtt.ItemsSource = dtAtt.Select("Att_Pkg=0");
```

Comment: What is the type that you are setting the ItemsSource to? DataTable, DataSet, custom object?

Comment: @Mike Schwartz, it is a `DataTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your your source you're binding in the code just a bit. Try this:

```
lstAtt.ItemsSource = dtAtt.Select("Att_Pkg=0").CopyToDataTable().DefaultView;
```